# Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use a project which my teacher gave to me, but it shows me an error

```
    Settings file '/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/HTTPNetworking/settings.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'HTTPNetworking'.
> Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_d1xerae4a210x6r7efckrwyki$_run_closure1@580a3803] on settings 'HTTPNetworking' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'HTTPNetworking'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_d1xerae4a210x6r7efckrwyki$_run_closure1@580a3803] on settings 'HTTPNetworking' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings
at settings_d1xerae4a210x6r7efckrwyki.run(/Users/admin/AndroidStudioProjects/HTTPNetworking/settings.gradle:1)
```

settings.gradle contains:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
      repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
      }
}
rootProject.name = "HTTP Networking"
include ':app'
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4):

This error can be caused by defining the `dependencyResolutionManagement` block in a `build.gradle` file instead of in the **`settings.gradle`** (which is where the doco clearly tells you to put it).

Not that *I* did that or anything.
Feel free to upvote this answer if you also totally did not make that obviously dumb mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change your `distributionUrl`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

in `gradle-7.3` and lower method `dependencyResolutionManagement` have `@Incubating` annotation. To use this method in your `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` file you need to add the line:

```
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

Answer (score 1):

This error could be caused due to having an older gradle-version, the issue got resolved for me after i upgraded my gradle version to 7.4.2 for my project

Answer (score 0):

Copy and replace below codes in `Top-level build file` :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and make comment these lines in settings.gardle(:) :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Note that `Gradle Version` better to be **6.6** for `Gradle Plugin` **4.1.3**