# Gradle 6.0.1 dependencyResolutionManagement fails

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, pipeline

A Jenkins pipeline is running for my project which contains `dependencyResolutionManagement` in my `settings.gradle`.

On my local machine Gradle version 7.4.2 is installed and everything works fine, but when the pipeline attempts to run a `gradle clean build` inside a docker container via Jenkins, it fails. This has Gradle version 6.0.1.

The original error is: `Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments`

With the use of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150086/could-not-find-method-dependencyresolutionmanagement-for-arguments), I added `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")` in the `settings.gradle`, but this gives the following error: `There is no feature named VERSION_CATALOGS`

My `settings.gradle` currently looks like this:

```
enableFeaturePreview('VERSION_CATALOGS')
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this error without updating the Gradle version for Jenkins? I would prefer not to do this, since other projects are also dependent on this Gradle version.

Comment: please update the question by adding you're `setting.gradle`

Comment: just added it @George